# Definition of sheaf using equalizer

Tags: algebraic-geometry, category-theory, sheaf-theory

Wikipedia give sheaf property using equalizer diagram by saying sheaf property means for any open cover $\{U_i\}$ of $U$

$$F(U) \rightarrow \prod_{i} F(U_i) {{{} \atop \longrightarrow}\atop{\longrightarrow \atop {}}} \prod_{i, j} F(U_i \cap U_j)$$

is an equalizer. What means two arrows? If $i = 1,2,3$ then what means

$$F(U) \rightarrow F(U_1) \times F(U_2) \times F(U_3) {{{} \atop \longrightarrow}\atop{\longrightarrow \atop {}}} F(U_1 \cap U_2) \times F(U_2 \cap U_3) \times F(U_1 \cap U_3)?$$

Comment: There are textual descriptions above and below the indicated diagram at the cited Wikipedia article. Have you read those?

Comment: @ZhenLin I read it but I still don't understand. I am confused what is meant there.

Comment: Is there a typo when you say:
Similarly , fo each of $i,j \in I$, we have a map $b_{i,j}$:
$$res^{U_j}_{U_i \cap U_j} \circ p_j : \prod_{i \in I} F(U_i) \rightarrow F(U_i \cap U_j)$$. Shouldn't it be:
$$res^{U_j}_{U_i \cap U_j} \circ p_j : \prod_{i \in I} F(U_j) \rightarrow F(U_i \cap U_j)$$
because you are restricting $U_j$ to $U_i \cap U_j$ unless I am not understanding something. Sorry i couldnt put that in comments because my reputation is not 50 above!!

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Given maps $f:X\to Y$ and $g:X\to Y$, a natural way of writing them together in the same diagram would be like this:
$$X{{f\atop {\Large\longrightarrow}}\atop{{\Large\longrightarrow}\atop g}}Y$$
A map $\mathrm{eq}:E\to X$ is an equalizer ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equaliser_%28mathematics%29#In_category_theory)) of the maps $f$ and $g$ if it is final in the category of maps to $X$ that equalize $f$ and $g$. Depicting it together with the maps $f$ and $g$, we say that 
$$E\xrightarrow{\;\mathrm{eq}\;} X{{f\atop {\Large\longrightarrow}}\atop{{\Large\longrightarrow}\atop g}}Y$$
is an equalizer diagram.

---

Let $X$ be a topological space, let $F$ be a presheaf on $X$, and let $\{U_i\}_{i\in I}$ be an open cover of $X$. The presheaf $F$ comes with restriction maps $\mathrm{res}_{V}^{U}:F(U)\to F(V)$ for each pair of open sets $U,V$ with $V\subseteq U$. In particular, for each pair of $i,j\in I$, we have restriction maps $$\large\mathrm{res}_{U_i\cap U_j}^{U_i}:F(U_i)\to F(U_i\cap U_j)$$ and  $$\large\mathrm{res}_{U_i\cap U_j}^{U_j}:F(U_j)\to F(U_i\cap U_j).$$
By definition, for each $i\in I$, the product ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_%28mathematics%29)) $\prod_{i\in I}F(U_i)$ comes with a projection map 
$$p_i:\prod_{i\in I}F(U_i)\longrightarrow F(U_i).$$ Moreover, $F(U_i)$ comes with a restriction map $\mathrm{res}_{U_i\cap U_j}^{U_i}:F(U_i)\to F(U_i\cap U_j)$ for each $j\in I$. Composing them, we have for each pair of $i,j\in I$, a map $a_{i,j}$, as follows:
$$\underbrace{(\mathrm{res}_{U_i\cap U_j}^{U_i}\circ p_i)}_{\Large a_{i,j}}:\prod_{i\in I}F(U_i)\longrightarrow F(U_i\cap U_j)$$
By the definition of a product, these $a_{i,j}$'s induce a map (let's call it $\alpha$) from $\prod_{i\in I}F(U_i)$ to the product of all of the $F(U_i\cap U_j)$'s together:
$$\alpha:\prod_{i\in I}F(U_i)\longrightarrow \prod_{i,j\in I}F(U_i\cap U_j).$$
Similarly, for each pair of $i,j\in I$, we have a map $b_{i,j}$:
$$\underbrace{(\mathrm{res}_{U_i\cap U_j}^{U_j}\circ p_j)}_{\Large b_{i,j}}:\prod_{i\in I}F(U_i)\longrightarrow F(U_i\cap U_j)$$
which come together to form a single map
$$\beta:\prod_{i\in I}F(U_i)\longrightarrow \prod_{i,j\in I}F(U_i\cap U_j).$$
These maps $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are the top and bottom arrows in the diagram
$$F(U) \longrightarrow \prod_{i\in I} F(U_i) {{{}\atop {\Large\longrightarrow}}\atop{{\Large\longrightarrow}\atop {}}}\prod_{i, j\in I} F(U_i \cap U_j)$$
We say that $F$ is a sheaf ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sheaf_%28mathematics%29#Sheaves)) if, for any open cover $\{U_i\}_{i\in I}$ of our space $X$, this diagram is an equalizer diagram.

---

Note that $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are **not** the same map; they take different "paths". Let's trace out what happens: the top-right path is $a_{i,j}$, and the bottom-left path is $b_{i,j}$.  $\require{AMScd}$
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
\prod_{i\in I}F(U_i) @>{\Large p_i}>> F(U_i);\\
@V{\Large p_j}VV @VV{\Large\mathrm{res}_{U_i\cap U_j}^{U_i}}V \\
F(U_j) @>>{\Large\mathrm{res}_{U_i\cap U_j}^{U_j}}> F(U_i\cap U_j);
\end{CD}$$
The two maps $\alpha$ and $\beta$ to the product $\prod_{i,j\in I}F(U_i\cap U_j)$ agree on a specific element $(s_i)_{i\in I}$ of the product $\prod_{i\in I}F(U_i)$ **if and only if** $a_{i,j}$ and $b_{i,j}$ agree on it for all pairs of $i,j\in I$. But $a_{i,j}$ and $b_{i,j}$ are clearly going to be different maps in general, so this is not a trivial condition.

Comment: @Zee: The comment below is wrong, the product
$$\prod_{i\in I}F(U_j)$$
is just $F(U_j)$ to the power $|I|$ (the cardinality of $I$), a very different object than $$\prod_{i\in I}F(U_i)$$

Comment: It looks to me like one either has to distinguish between $F(U_i \cap U_j)$ and $F(U_j \cap U_i)$, or  that one has to specify for each unordered pair $(i,j)$ which of the two maps $\prod_{i} F(U_i) \to F(U_i \cap U_j)$ one is choosing for $\alpha$ and which for $\beta$.

Comment: @Improve I think the point here is considering ordered pairs instead of unordered pairs. It is important which open set is at the left and which one is at the right position.

Comment: @Improve I think it should be considered as ordered pairs too. Given the OP’s example, it should be the product of 9 sets, rather than just 3 sets.

Comment: "Moreover, F(Ui) comes with a restriction map [...]"  gets confusing because you already said that two lines above so the "Moreover [...]" makes it sound like it's some new data.

Comment: @ZevChonoles Thank you so much for this explanation.  It is the best on the internet.